# Connection timeout while trying to send an email using Django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-email, django-errors

I am trying to build a module which allows me to send an email to users. 
However, I am facing an error:

*TimeoutError at /email 
[Errno 60] Operation timed out*

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from emailfunction.views import send_email

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^email', send_email),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def send_email(request):
    subject = 'Test Subject'
    message = 'Test Message./n 123 123 456 456 778 990./n From ABC/n'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_list = ['receiver@gmail.com', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse("Mail has been sent. Please check your mail. Thank YOU!")
```

Relevant details from settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: Can you check if the port is blocked by your home / university / company firewall? Easiest way is to setup the sender address with your credentials in thunderbird or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what Thunderbird is or how to use it in my case. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Turns out it was being blocked by the firewall. I didn't realize that. Thank you so much!